# No duplicate entry for Idnumber in addStudent.php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

This is the addStudent.php. **what should I do, not to have duplicate IdNumber when the admin(I) will add a new student**. Sorry I tried some samples that I saw in the web but its not working. Sorry Beginner. If you need the sql just let me know.

**`addStudent.php`**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
include "connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
 $IDNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['IDNumber']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
 $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
 $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
 $middlename = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['middlename']);
 $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['course']);
 $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['year']);
 $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['birthdate']);
 $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
 $citizenship = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['citizenship']);
 $religion = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['religion']);
 $birthplace = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['birthplace']);
 $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nationality']);
 $home_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['home_address']);
 $home_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['home_no']);
 $bag_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['baguio_add']);
 $bag_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bag_no']);
 $contactNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['contactNo']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
 $father = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['father']);
 $fatherOcc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fatherOcc']);
 $mother = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mother']);
 $motherOcc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['motherOcc']);
 $guardian = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['guardian']);
 $guardianAdd = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['guardianAdd']);
 $guardianRel = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['guardianRel']);
 $guardianNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['guardianNo']);
 //(IDNumber, password, lastname, firstname, middlename, course, year,     birthdate,gender, citizenship, religion, Birthplace, Nationality, HomeAddress, homeNumber, BaguioAddress, BaguioNo, contactNo, email, father, fatherOcc, mother, motherOcc, guardian, guardianAdd, guardianRel, guardianNo) 
 $query1=mysqli_query($db, "insert into student (IDNumber, password,  lastname, firstname, middlename, course, year, birthdate,gender, citizenship, religion, Birthplace, Nationality, HomeAddress, homeNumber, BaguioAddress, BaguioNo, contactNo, email, father, fatherOcc, mother, motherOcc, guardian, guardianAdd, guardianRel, guardianNo) 
values(
'{$_POST['IDNumber']}',
'{$_POST['password']}',
'{$_POST['lastname']}',
'{$_POST['firstname']}',
'{$_POST['middlename']}',
'{$_POST['course']}',
'{$_POST['year']}',
'{$_POST['birthdate']}',
'{$_POST['gender']}',
'{$_POST['citizenship']}',
'{$_POST['religion']}',
'{$_POST['birthplace']}',
'{$_POST['nationality']}',
'{$_POST['home_address']}',
'{$_POST['home_no']}',
'{$_POST['baguio_add']}',
'{$_POST['bag_no']}',
'{$_POST['contactNo']}',
'{$_POST['email']}',
'{$_POST['father']}',
'{$_POST['fatherOcc']}',
'{$_POST['mother']}',
'{$_POST['motherOcc']}',
'{$_POST['guardian']}',
'{$_POST['guardianAdd']}',
'{$_POST['guardianRel']}',
'{$_POST['guardianNo']}'
 )");

if($query1)
    {
    header("Location: viewStudent.php");
    }
  }
  ?>

 <h4>Add Student</h4>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>ID Number:<input type="text" required="required" name="IDNumber" maxlength="7" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>Password:<input type="text" required="required" name="password" placeholder="6-10 characters" maxlength="10" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>Last Name:<input type="text" required="required" name="lastname" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>First Name:<input type="text" required="required" name="firstname" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>Middle Name:<input type="text" required="required" name="middlename" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>Course:
        <select name="course">
        <option value="Associate in Accounting Technology (AAT)">Associate in Accounting Technology (AAT)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Acccountancy (BSAc)">Bachelor of Science in Acccountancy (BSAc)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Business Economics (BSBA Bus Econ)">Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Business Economics (BSBA Bus Econ)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Financial Management (BSBA FinMan)">Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Financial Management (BSBA FinMan)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Human Resource Management Development (BSBA HRDM)">Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Human Resource Management Development (BSBA HRDM)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Marketing (BSBA Mktg)">Bachelor of Science in Business Administration major in Marketing (BSBA Mktg)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Entrepreneurship (BS Entrep)">Bachelor of Science in Entrepreneurship (BS Entrep)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Hospitality and Tourism Management major in Hotel, Resort and Restaurant Management (BSHTM HRMM">Bachelor of Science in Hospitality and Tourism Management major in Hotel, Resort and Restaurant Management (BSHTM HRMM</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Hospitality and Tourism Management major in Travel and Tours Management (BSHTM TTM)">Bachelor of Science in Hospitality and Tourism Management major in Travel and Tours Management (BSHTM TTM)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Management Accountancy (BSMA)">Bachelor of Science in Management Accountancy (BSMA)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (BSCS)">Bachelor of Science in Computer Science (BSCS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Information Technology (BSIT)">Bachelor of Science in Information Technology (BSIT)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Information Management (BSIS)">Bachelor of Science in Information Management (BSIS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Mathematics (BS Math)">Bachelor of Science in Mathematics (BS Math)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Library and Information Science (BLIS)">Bachelor of Library and Information Science (BLIS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Architecture (BS Arch)">Bachelor of Science in Architecture (BS Arch)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering (BSChE)">Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering (BSChE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering (BSCE)">Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering (BSCE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Electrical Engineering (BSEE)">Bachelor of Science in Electrical Engineering (BSEE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Electronics Engineering (BSECE)">Bachelor of Science in Electronics Engineering (BSECE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Geodetic Engineering (BSGE)">Bachelor of Science in Geodetic Engineering (BSGE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Industrial Engineering (BSIE)">Bachelor of Science in Industrial Engineering (BSIE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Mechanical Engineering (BSME)">Bachelor of Science in Mechanical Engineering (BSME)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Mechatronics Engineering (BS MecE)">Bachelor of Science in Mechatronics Engineering (BS MecE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Mining Engineering (BSEM)">Bachelor of Science in Mining Engineering (BSEM)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in Communication (BA Com)">Bachelor of Arts in Communication (BA Com)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in English (BA Engl)">Bachelor of Arts in English (BA Engl)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in Legal Studies (BA LS)">Bachelor of Arts in Legal Studies (BA LS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in Philosophy and Interdisciplinary Studies (BA PIS)">Bachelor of Arts in Philosophy and Interdisciplinary Studies (BA PIS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in Political Science (BA Polit Sc)">Bachelor of Arts in Political Science (BA Polit Sc)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Arts in Religious and Values Studies (BARVS)">Bachelor of Arts in Religious and Values Studies (BARVS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Psychology (BS Psych)">Bachelor of Science in Psychology (BS Psych)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Social Work (BS Sol Wk)">Bachelor of Science in Social Work (BS Sol Wk)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Nursing (BSN)">Bachelor of Science in Nursing (BSN)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor in Medical Laboratory Science(BMLS)">Bachelor in Medical Laboratory Science(BMLS)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Biology (BS Biol)">Bachelor of Science in Biology (BS Biol)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Pharmacy (BS Pharm)">Bachelor of Science in Pharmacy (BS Pharm)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Radiologic Technology (BSRT)">Bachelor of Science in Radiologic Technology (BSRT)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in General Education (BEED Gen Ed)">Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in General Education (BEED Gen Ed)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in Pre-School Education (BEED Pre Schl)">Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in Pre-School Education (BEED Pre Schl)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in Special Education (BEED SPED)">Bachelor of Elementary Education with specialization in Special Education (BEED SPED)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Elementary Educ major in Tech & He (BEED THE)">Bachelor of Elementary Educ major in Tech & He (BEED THE)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Elementary Educ major in Values Educ (BEED VAL)">Bachelor of Elementary Educ major in Values Educ (BEED VAL)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Biological Sciences (BSED Biol Sc)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Biological Sciences (BSED Biol Sc)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in English (BSED Engl)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in English (BSED Engl)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Filipino (BSED Fil)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Filipino (BSED Fil)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Filipino (BSED Fil)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Filipino (BSED Fil)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Mathematics (BSED Math)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Mathematics (BSED Math)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Musics, Arts, Physical Education, and Health (BSED MAPEH)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Musics, Arts, Physical Education, and Health (BSED MAPEH)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Physical Sciences (BSED Phys Sc)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Physical Sciences (BSED Phys Sc)</option>
        <option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Social Studies (BSED Soc Stds)">Bachelor of Secondary Education major in Social Studies (BSED Soc Stds)</option>
    </select>
    <p>Year:<input type="number" max="5" min="1" required="required" name="year" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"><br>
    <p>Birthdate:<input type="date" required="required" name="birthdate" max= '<?php echo date('Y') - 14; ?>-01-01' min="1990-01-01"><br>
    <p>Gender:<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required"
    <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") //echo "checked";?>
        value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender"
    <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") //echo "checked";?>
        value="male">Male
    <p>Citizenship:<input type="text" required="required" name="citizenship" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)" /><br>
    <p>Religion:
    <select name="religion">
        <option value="Aglipay">Aglipay</option>
        <option value="Born Again">Born Again</option>
        <option value="Iglesia ni Cristo">Iglesia ni Cristo</option>
        <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
        <option value="Jehovah's Witness">Jehovah's Witness</option>
        <option value="Methodist">Methodist</option>
        <option value="Mormon">Mormon</option>
        <option value="Pentecost">Pentecost</option>
        <option value="Protestant">Protestant</option>
        <option value="Roman Catholic">Roman Catholic</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
        <option value="Others">N/A</option>
    </select>
    <p>Birth Place:<input type="text" required="required" name="birthplace" maxlength="150" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"/>
    <p>Nationality:<input type="text" required="required" name="nationality" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
    <p>Home Address:<input type="text" required="required" name="home_address" maxlength="150" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"/>
    <p>Home ContactNo.:<input type="text" required="required" name="home_no"  maxlength="11" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>Baguio Address:<input type="text" required="required" name="baguio_add" maxlength="150" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+">
    <p>Baguio Contact No.:<input type="text" required="required" name="bag_no"  maxlength="11" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>Contact No.:<input type="text" required="required" name="contactNo"  maxlength="11" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>email:<input type="email" required="required" name="email">
    <p>Name of Father:<input type="text" name="father" maxlength="20" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+"/>
    <p>Occupation of Father:<input type="text" name="fatherOcc" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>Name of Mother:<input type="text" name="mother" maxlength="20" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+"/>
    <p>Occupation of Mother:<input type="text" name="motherOcc" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>Guardian:<input type="text" name="guardian" maxlength="20" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+"/>
    <p>Guardian Address:<input type="text" name="guardianAdd" maxlength="150" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"/>
    <p>Relationship With Guardian:<input type="text" name="guardianRel"  maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidateAlpha(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)"/>
    <p>Guardian Contact No.:<input type="text" name="guardianNo" maxlength="11" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit">                                      
    </form>
    </p>

  </article>


                <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy;Saint Louis University 2015 </p>   
    </footer>

 <script type="application/javascript">
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 function ValidateAlpha(evt)
 {
    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if ((keyCode < 65 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 123) && keyCode != 32)

    return false;
        return true;
  }
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 function nospaces(t){
   if(t.value.match(/\s/g)){
  t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
  }
 }
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function alpha(e) {
 var k;
document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: In the database, set the IDnumber to be primary or unique, and then perhaps use auto_increment?

Answer (score 2):

Set the ID number as the primary key in the database. You could also add a unique index.

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) page shows you how to do so.